# Как вставить символ в текст

Tags: алгоритм

Вопрос может одним показаться простым, а другим нет!

Собственно в чем суть:

Есть некоторая программа в которой нужно реализовать данный алгоритм, чтобы он был менее ресурсоемким насколько это возможно. У нас имеется некоторый текст, он может быть очень большим на несколько десятков страниц. Нужно допустим вставить символ между буквами в слове `(...Првет...)`. Как это можно реализовать учитывая что это одно слово в большом тексте?

P.S Первое что мне пришло в голову это скопировать часть текста откуда у нас получается неправильное место `(вет...)` в буфер или переменную, потом в правильный текст вставить необходимый символ `(и) -> (...При)` и долить оставшейся частью `(...Привет...)`. Правда при таком алгоритме придется копировать десятки страниц, если опечатка в тексте закралась где-нибудь в начале.

Comment: "несколько десятков страниц" это не много. Говорить о "менее ресурсоемким насколько это возможно", не зная ни языка реализации, ни железа, ни других операций, которые вы хотите с текстом выполнять, ни характерных примеров текста, не очень полезно.  Начните с самого просто (копируйте при вставке), а если это окажется слишком медленно, тогда имея рабочий код будет ясно насколько его следует улучшить. Связанный вопрос: [Text editor theory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3169440/4279)

Answer (score 1):

> алгоритм, чтобы он был менее ресурсоемким насколько это возможно

На мой взгляд, если текстовый буфер имеет некоторый запас свободного места и написать маленькую ассемблерную вставку, менее ресурсоёмкое ничего не придумать:

1. Сдвигаем "хвост" буфера на один символ к концу буфера
2. В появившуюся "дырку" пишем вставляемый символ.

Почти все ресурсы занимает пункт 1. Вот его и попытаемся реализовать через ассемблерную вставку как-то так:

```
LEA SI, Buffer+offset
LEA DI, SI+1
MOV CX, LengthOfTail
REP MOVSB
```

Понятно, что операнды этих команд я показал чисто условно, но смысл, я думаю, довольно очевиден. Таким образом, если Вам понадобиться вставить символ в самое начало текста размером в 1 МБ, то на проце с тактовой частотой в 1 GHz это займёт около 1 мс.

Comment: *"менее ресурсоёмкое ничего не придумать"* —квадратичный алгоритм на ассемблере проиграет более эффективному алгоритму на чистом Питоне на достаточно  большом тексте.

Comment: **квадратичный алгоритм на ассемблере** не понял... Почему он КВАДРАТИЧНЫЙ ?  Команда MOVSB выполняется ровно LengthOfTail раз! Я вижу здесь ЛИНЕЙНУЮ зависимость от длины текста.

Comment: И рискуем проиграть по сравнению с хорошим оптимизирующим компилятором :) Да и одна мс для вставки 1 символа - это многовато. Словом, я к тому, что никакая реализация на самом крутом ассемблере плохой идеи не имеет смысла.

Comment: Вы можете высказать хотя бы одну идею о том, как **хороший оптимизирующий компилятор** может прооптимизировать эти 4 команды?  Превратить их в две команды? Или включить ускорение проца до сверхсветовой скорости? Идея оптимизации в чём заключается? Кстати, пересыл память-память выполняется через DMA, так что, полагаю, здесь подключится аппаратная оптимизация.

Comment: @Sergey рассмотрите задачу вставки `n` символов (по символу за раз в разные позиции).

Comment: Ну да, а если рассмотреть задачу вставки n**2 символов, то сложность будет кубическая! :-)

Comment: @Sergey это конечно все круто, ассемблер! Ставлю плюс только за это. Но писать программу на ассемблере, нет спасибо!

Comment: @Sergey Конечно, могу :) Он может умнее использовать кэш, выравнивание, особенности процессора, какие-нибудь SIMD и еще кучу других вещей. **Скорость работы программы давно уже не определяется скоростью выполнения ассемблерных команд.** Это вам не древние XT :)

Comment: **Но писать программу на ассемблере, нет спасибо!** Ну какая же это программа - 4 строки всего. :-) Но, если уж такая идиосинкразия на ассемлер, то тогда два совета, которые здесь уже прозвучали: 1) Использовать memmove (Harry) 2) Организовать работу редактора по строкам (Harry). Во времена своей далёкой молодости :-(, когда я писал редактор для LSI/11, я именно так и сделал - в редакторе был массив указателей на строки, а превращались они в поток символов только при записи в файл. Кстати, очень легко было переставлять строки(правим только указатели), удалять строки.

Comment: **Он может умнее использовать кэш** - "Надежды юношей питают..." :-)  Если говорить серьёзно, то оптимизация самого компилятора - очень сложная задача. В своё время, теоретические основы этого всего заложил А.П. Ершов. И его компилятор "Альфа" долго оставался самым лучшим (по оптимизации) в мире. Для осуществления оптимизации этот компилятор делал 35 проходов по тексту программы. С тех пор ситуация сильно усложнилась: процы выполняют тысячи разных команд, организация компа на каждой материнке - своя. Построить УНИВЕРСАЛЬНЫЙ оптимизирующий компилятор НЕВОЗМОЖНО.

Comment: @Sergey Для того и масса ключиков с целевой архитектурой и процессорами (да и еще куда других) у компиляторов. Да и наука со времен Ершова не стояла на месте. Все-таки с тех времен (даже если брать Альфу-6 и 1975 год) прошло 40 лет, за которые придумано много разных гитик :) Думаю, не ошибусь, если скажу, что во втором "Драконе" как минимум половина теории оптимизации придумана после 1990 года, да и сейчас хватает новых разработок.

Comment: Вот, что пишет по этому поводу специалист, занимающийся оптимизацией одного из лучших С компилятора (от Intel): "Поэтому, на мой взгляд, не существует простого универсального работающего метода оценки эффективности работы приложения и, следовательно, простых путей его улучшения." Т.е. мы даже не можем ИЗМЕРИТЬ оптимизацию, а уж наадеяться на неё... :-( (https://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/157671/)

Comment: **Для того и масса ключиков** Заело меня любопытство :-) Посмотрел. Оказалось, что для GCC имеется 226 (!!!) ключей оптимизации... Вам не кажется. что это уже - перебор? Вот лично Вы, используете какие ключи оптимизации кроме -O2 ? :-) Плюс, сюда же, 108 опций, конкретизирующих особенности х86 архитектуры. Вам не кажется, что этот факт - наглядное доказательство того, что никакой АВТОМАТИЧЕСКОЙ оптимизации нет и в помине. Ну, ПОЧТИ нет... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы держите текст в одном большом блоке - то в любом случае его надо раздвигать (при этом совсем не нужно копировать кусок текста в переменную - просто с конца сдвигать его вправо на нужное количество символов; лишь бы размер буфера позволял обойтись без выделения нового).

Но при большом тексте - может, лучше хранить его частями, в блоках меньшего размера? Вплоть до того, что каждая строка в своем блоке? Тогда редактирование будет затрагивать только небольшой кусок.

Comment: Я подумывал использовать массив для использования каждой строки, в своей ячейке. Кстати а как можно раздвинуть? Допустим на языке с++.

Comment: Допустим, с места `s` нужно вставить `k` символов (`char`) из `p`. `memmove` гарантирует корректную обработку перекрывающихся областей, так что - `memmove(s+k, s, strlen(s)+1);` и `memcpy(s,p,k);`.

Comment: Кстати, если это интерактивный редактор :) - то можно вырезать отдельную строку, работать с ней - мало ли какие в ней правки? - а уже по окончании работы заменить ею строку в большом тексте. Если это C++ - можно попробовать что-то типа `list<string>`... Пока вы не измените сам главный алгоритм, все попытки ускорения за счет ассемблера - паллиатив...

Comment: Ага именно интерактивный, угадали =) Проблема в том что вдобавок это еще и сетевой редактор, так что не получится работать с отдельной строкой. Нужно чтобы подключившиеся могли видеть изменения посимвольно онлайн. P.S Ассемблер, нет он не нужен, мне нужен алгоритм который сможет именно максимально ускорить работу с текстом

Comment: А кто мешает отображать на экране именно эту, изменяемую строку (если я правильно понял задачу)? Кстати, насколько я помню, в свое время Turbo Vision (а он есть в исходниках и пояснениях :)) использовал в своем простеньком редакторе именно эту идею - текущей работы с отдельно вынутым буфером. На тех машинах это было существенно.

Comment: Что значит отображать изменяемую строку? Изменяется допустим большой по размеру текст. И как тогда определить строку? Сделать определяемый символ типа `\n`?